# Binary image labeling in MATLAB with Hough transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have this binary image:
[image]

I'd like to label pixels lying on the same line
like this:
[image]

I tried Hough transform. However, as you see it failed finding all lines. 
does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Might be a matter of the threshold you're using, right? Those unidentified lines have fewer pixels voting so you'd expect the "vote" intensity for those lines in the Hough transform to be smaller. Have you tried changing threshold?

Comment: ...or decreasing hough space resolution, since your lines are not perfectly straight.

Comment: Thanks for your comments

Comment: I'm not sure if Hough transform is a good choice or not. Let me change my question. 
I need to label vessels in [this image][1]. I could [segment vessels][2] but the only problem is that blobs are connected at optic disk. How can I label each vessel?


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/50MCC.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dpCch.jpg

Comment: Are you satisfied with your segmentation? I guess with a Frangi Filter you can improve it. For labelling, you can use watershed to detach connected segments.

Answer (score 0):

Hough should be just fine for this application. As Falimond and gfkri suggested, a few parameter tweaks to the standard Hough technique will help.

A few ideas:

1. Instead of counting Hough votes, determine line density. Once you've found a number of candidate lines, determine the maximum number of pixels each line would occupy in the image. (Lines through the center are longer than lines through points near the corners.) Divide the bin count [votes] by the maximum possible line length to yield line density. Then filter by line density. When you follow this technique, you'll often need to set thresholds for both density and minimum length--you don't want to find 8-pixel segments that happen to be straight but slightly angled from the line to which they belong.
2. Dilate the image first; from the look of it, you could dilate quite a bit. When the white pixel clumps are dilated, there will be a higher density of points along a Hough fit line. After dilation, you can also downsample the image (e.g. from 640x480 to 160x120) to reduce the number of points you have to process. [You could also apply Gaussian blur to generate a grayscale image. This maintains the original edge point(s) as the strongest peaks. You would then use weighted intensity values in your Hough accumulator.]
3. As an alternative to (2) dilation, for each (x,y) white pixel in the image add votes to your accumulator bins for all its neighbor pixels, too: (x-1,y-1), (x, y-1), . . . (x+1,y+1). This might be a quicker change to your code.
4. Reduce your angular resolution. That is, if your Hough accumulator using angular increments of 1 degree, try an angular increment of 2 degrees.
5. Take your (R,theta) accumulator plot--which you can consider as a sort of 2D intensity image--and smooth it out before identifying peaks. You might only need smoothing if you tend to get two nearly overlapping lines because the points along what you think should be one line are scattered in bimodal clumps.

Long story short: make the task simpler by reducing effective resolution, as gfkri suggested. Think of fitting an N-pixel thick Hough line segment rather than a 1-pixel Hough line.